# Tensorflow Serving number of requests in queue

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, prometheus, tensorflow-serving

I have my own TensorFlow serving server for multiple neural networks. Now I want to estimate the load on it. Does somebody know how to get the current number of requests in a queue in TensorFlow serving? I tried using Prometheus, but there is no such option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually ,the tf serving doesn't have requests queue , which means that the tf serving would't rank the requests, if there are too many requests. 
The only thing that tf serving would  do is allocating  a threads pool, when the server is  initialized.
when  a request coming , the tf serving will use a unused thread to deal with the request , if there are no free threads, the tf serving will return a  unavailable error.and the client shoule retry again later.
you can find the these information in the comments of tensorflow_serving/batching/streaming_batch_schedulor.h

Comment: Thanks for explonation! I perfomed some stress tests for serving and when I send about 10 000 requests per second, serving failed with error " Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: The batch scheduling queue to which this task was submitted is full".Can you please explain that?

Answer (score 0):

what 's more ,you can assign the number of threads by the --rest_api_num_threads or let it empty and automatically configured by tf serivng